# How to print html text in new line when pusing data from javascript backend

Tags: javascript, html, newline, line-breaks, lwc

formatPopupBodyText(serverPayload) {
let result = this.formatBusinessHoursText(serverPayload);

```
    if (serverPayload.PhoneNumbers__c != null && getCurrentCountryCode() === 'IN' && (this.brandName == 'HYN' || this.brandName == 'SUZ')) {
       
        result += `. ${LABEL_NATIONALNETWORK} `;
    }
   
    this.popupBodyText = result;
}
```

### Right now it is showing as below: as a single statement::

We are open from Monday to Friday from 9am to 6pm. Contact us at 80004001. (Call to the national network).

**I tried below code but didn't work:**

formatPopupBodyText(serverPayload) {
let result = this.formatBusinessHoursText(serverPayload);

```
    if (serverPayload.PhoneNumbers__c != null && getCurrentCountryCode() === 'IN' && (this.brandName == 'HYN' || this.brandName == 'SUZ')) {
       
        result += `\n ${LABEL_NATIONALNETWORK} `; **//put "\n" and tried with "<br/>" as well**
    }
   
    this.popupBodyText = result;
}
```

### Output should be like below means each sentence should be in new line. But right now it is showing in a single statement::

We are open from Monday to Friday from 9am to 6pm.
Contact us at 80004001.
(Call to the national network).

Comment: have you tried using `<br>` ? you would have to use encoded html in you text something like `&lt;br/&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the newline character \n or HTML tag < br > and some modification

```
formatPopupBodyText(serverPayload) {
  let result = this.formatBusinessHoursText(serverPayload);

  if (serverPayload.PhoneNumbers__c != null && getCurrentCountryCode() === 'IN' 
  && (this.brandName == 'HYN' || this.brandName == 'SUZ')) {
  result += `<br>${LABEL_NATIONALNETWORK}`; // add <br> tag before the label
 }

 this.popupBodyText = result;
}
```